# How to return the Value from Column A on the row where the Max of Column B is found in a subquery

Tags: t-sql, subquery, max, row-number

I have time series data and I am creating a rolling average over a 90 sample window (15 min).  I then want to find the max 15 min window each hour so the data is grouped by Hour.  However I want to also return the start or end time stamp of the max 15 min window.  Currently I am only returning the time stamp at the start of each hour.

Here is an example of the data that I start with:

```
theDate    theTime     value
4/30/2019   22:47:53    0
4/30/2019   22:47:43    0
4/30/2019   22:47:33    0
4/30/2019   22:47:23    0
4/30/2019   22:47:13    0
4/30/2019   22:47:03    0
4/30/2019   22:46:53    0
4/30/2019   22:46:43    0
```

I have tried row_number() and filtered where but I don't think I am applying them correctly for this as there are several nested sub-queries.

```
select
        min([theDate]) as theDate, 
        min([theTime]) as theTime, 
        max([Value]) as maxValue, 
        max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM,
        timeHour as timeHour

from( select [theDate], [theTime], [Value],
       avg(windowAvg) over(order by theDate DESC, theTime rows between 90 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg,
       datepart(hh,theTime) as timeHour
  from (select [theDate], [theTime], [Value], sum([Value]) as windowAvg
          from [Data].[dbo].[tOne]
          Where ([theDate] > convert(DAte,DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())))
          group by theDate, theTime, Value 

          )tOneTemp   
          )tOneTempTwo
          group by theDate, timeHour
          order by theDate DESC, theTime DESC
```

I am looking for the table below except that instead of theTime always being the min per hour as I have it calculated I would like it to be a value within the 15 min window of that the MaxDM was calculated.

Here is an example of what I end up with using my current Code:

```
theDate    theTime   maxValue   maxDM       timeHour
2019-04-30  22:00:04    508.8   660.643956  22
2019-04-30  21:00:03    1071.3  798.206593  21
2019-04-30  20:00:03    1022.2  817.539560  20
2019-04-30  19:00:04    871.4   574.786813  19
2019-04-30  18:00:04    944.0   670.095604  18
```

What I would like to see is something like this such that "theTime" reflects the start of the "maxValue" window.

Here is an example of what I would like to see (*note theTime):

```
theDate    theTime   maxValue   maxDM       timeHour
2019-04-30  22:10:34    508.8   660.643956  22
2019-04-30  21:45:03    1071.3  798.206593  21
2019-04-30  20:12:03    1022.2  817.539560  20
2019-04-30  19:32:04    871.4   574.786813  19
2019-04-30  18:56:04    944.0   670.095604  18
```

Thanks Ali here are the few mods I made to your code to fix some errors but the "TheTimeOfMaxDM" returns as "NULL" for all rows.

```
                    min([theDate]) as theDate, 
                    min([theTime]) as theTime, 
                    (select top(1) r.[theTime] from RunningAvg15Min r where 
                        r.[theDate]=(select min([theDate]) from RunningAvg15Min) and
                        r.[theTime]>=(select min([theTime]) from RunningAvg15Min)
                        and r.rolling_avg=(select max([rolling_avg]) from RunningAvg15Min)) as TheTimeOfMaxDM,
                    max([KW]) as maxValue, 
                    max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM,
                    timeHour as timeHour
                from RunningAvg15Min
                GROUP BY theDate, timeHour
                ORDER BY thedate DESC, thetime DESC
```

Comment: Rephrasing your question to clearly show sample starting input followed by the output you expect might be very helpful to others trying to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tim - I added the starting sample, what I get, and what I hope to get...the difference being "theTime" is now linked to maxValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your query in a CTE so I can use the subquery again. please check the below:-
so I added another output to your query called TheTimeOfMaxDM. hope this is what you need.

```
;with LastMonthData as (
               --get the data for the last month, and sum value if same time stamp is recorded (this is not logical)
               select [theDate], [theTime], [Value], sum([Value]) as windowAvg
                  from [tOne]
                  Where ([theDate] > convert(Date,DATEADD(month, -1, '2019-05-3')))--changed this to match the data provided.
                  group by theDate, theTime, Value 
          ),
RunningAvg15Min as (
                    select [theDate], [theTime], [Value],
                    avg(windowAvg) over(order by theDate DESC, theTime rows between 90 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg,
                    datepart(hh,theTime) as timeHour
                from LastMonthData
              ),DataSetGrouping as (
              select
                    min([theDate]) as theDate, 
                    min([theTime]) as theTime, 
                    min(datepart(hh,theTime)) as timeHour,
                    max([Value]) as maxValue, 
                    max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM
                from RunningAvg15Min
                GROUP BY
                    DATEPART(YEAR, TheDate),
                    DATEPART(MONTH, TheDate),
                    DATEPART(DAY, TheDate),
                    DATEPART(HOUR, TheTime),
                    (DATEPART(MINUTE, TheTime) / 60) ---change the 60 to 15, to change the grouping from per hour to per 15min

                )
                select * ,
                 (select top(1) r.[theTime] from RunningAvg15Min r where 
                        r.[theDate]=theDate
                        and r.[theTime]>=theTime
                        and r.rolling_avg=maxDM
                        order by r.[theDate],r.[theTime]
                        )  [TheTimeOfMaxDM]
                from DataSetGrouping
                ORDER BY thedate DESC, thetime DESC
```

Another note, I dont know if you need this or not , but if you wanted to group by 15 min, you could use the below in the grouping section

```
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, TheDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, TheDate),
    DATEPART(DAY, TheDate),
    DATEPART(HOUR, TheTime),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, TheTime) / 15)
```

I will try to validate a point, lets take for example the output row below:-

```
theDate     theTime             Value   rolling_avg         timeHour
2019-04-07  17:20:49.0000000    398.3   314.499999999997    17
```

On 2019-04-07 between hour 17 & 18, the max rolling_avg is 314.499999999997, and the time for that max was 17:20:49.0000000, we can see that be replacing the last part of the cte with the following:-

```
select * from RunningAvg15Min where rolling_avg between 314 and 315
                and thedate='2019-04-07' and theTime between '17:00:00' and '18:00:00'
```

output

```
theDate      theTime            Value   rolling_avg         timeHour
2019-04-07  17:20:49.0000000    398.3   314.499999999997    17
```

To summarize my answer, you can use CTE's in the fashion from the query I wrote to simplify the sub queries and to reference them more than once in your query if needed. hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Ali.  Please see what I added above to your code.  The logic seems sound but "TheTimeOfMaxDM" returns null values.

Comment: You did not get the main idea, you can't add separate queries for each field as you would get the first min value in the whole table. can you add the row dataset that provided your expected output so we can test against. your data example is not the one that produce the expected output you provided.

Comment: Hi Ali,

Here is a link to 3 Days of Data.  Columns C-E are raw data downloaded from SQL. Columns F-J are the columns I want calculated in the Query.  Everything is then filtered by Hour as is what I would want as well although it would be helpful to do it for different time intervals as well.  Thank You.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15oQCN96XBV8bOSuDD0R22HG2GK2rzl62/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated the query to be error free, and validated one point, but my results are different than yours, so hope that the new query will help you get to your desired output. And add the part to have different time intervals.

Comment: Yes, you got it.  Thank you for all the help.